# Concurrent quicksort in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, quick-sort

I have a task to write a concurrent version of `quicksort` algorithm, to speed it up. This is what I wrote:

```
template <class T>
void quicksort::sort(T *data, int len) {
    thread_count = 0;
    int p = 0;
    int r = len - 1;
    _sort(data, p, r);
}

template <class T>
void quicksort::_swap(T *data, int first, int second) {
    auto temp = data[first];
    data[first] = data[second];
    data[second] = temp;
}

template <class T>
void quicksort::_sort(T *data, int p, int r) {
    thread_count++;
    if (p < r) {
        auto q = _partition(data, p, r);
        if (thread_count >= thread_limit) {
            _sort(data, p, q - 1);
            _sort(data, q + 1, r);
        } else {
            std::thread lower(&quicksort::_sort<T>, this, data, p, q - 1);
            std::thread upper(&quicksort::_sort<T>, this, data, q + 1, r);
            lower.join();
            upper.join();
        }
    }
    thread_count--;
}

template <class T>
int quicksort::_partition(T *data, int p, int r) {
    auto first = data[p];
    auto last = data[r];
    T pivot = 0;
    // Median of three
    auto middle = data[(p + 2) / 2];
    if (first > middle) {
        if (middle > last) {
            pivot = middle;
        } else {
            pivot = last;
        }
    } else {
        if (middle > last) {
            pivot = std::max(first, last);
        } else {
            pivot = middle;
        }
    }
    auto i = p - 1;
    for (auto j = p; j < r; ++j) {
        if (data[j] <= pivot) {
            _swap(data, ++i, j);
        }
    }
    _swap(data, i + 1, r);
    return i + 1;
}
```

Those are methods from class `quicksort`, which also has `std::atomic<int> thread_limit` and `std::atomic<int> thread_count`.

So f.e I cap the thread limit to f.e maximum 1000 threads.

The part I am particularly not sure of is the part in `_sort()` function. Basically, I don't know if my way of starting those threads and then joining them is the right way to do it.

I have a benchmark method, and I benchmarked my quicksort implementation like this: I took the average of 100 benchmarks for every thread_limit from 200 to 2000, stepping by 100 (so 200, 300, 400) and for single-threaded quicksort of mine. And this was for `1.000.000`-sized arrays (every time I was creating a new one - this overhead was not measured). The result was shocking for me. It occurred, that of course, even with 2000 threads it was faster than with only 1 thread, but still, the fastest one was with `thread_limit = 200`. I thought that the optimum would be somewhere nearer the middle.

Sometimes f.e 700 threads were faster than 600 threads, but still, the general rule was: the more threads, the slower.

Do you guys see any flaws in my code or in my understanding of the benchmark I made?

Comment: Having more threads than are present in your hardware (likely 4 or 8 for typical laptops, possibly 12 for desktop) is not beneficial.

Comment: Okay. I have two cores and 4 threads in my laptop. Does it mean, that I actually should cap on 4 threads? Now I actually measured for thread_limit ranging from 20 to 800, and I still see that the more threads, the slower. 20 threads are faster than 40 etc.

Comment: @Frynio, more threads than hardware supports means more context switching. Context switches mean slower performance, and perhaps something else I'm unaware of (haven't designed or studied in depth any OS yet).

Comment: Every switch adds overhead. So if the overhead takes longer than the parallellisation improves, it's not helping.

Comment: You benchmarked your code, good. Did you verify it's output as well? As in, you know how long it takes, but does it work correctly?

Comment: I think I did. Are 100 arrays of length 1000 properly sorted an okay result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Partition - Pivot selection

There are 2 bugs in the pivot selection code, in combination allowing for \$\mathcal{O}(n^2)\$ worst case runtime.

#### Bug #1: Wrong average calculation

I guess this is just a typo:

```
auto middle = data[(p + 2) / 2];
```

Most likely, `(p + r) / 2` was intended instead, and that would fix this problem (disregarding overflow).

#### Bug #2: Missing a case

```
if (first > middle) {
    if (middle > last) {
        pivot = middle;
    } else {
        pivot = last;
    }
}
```

This snippet doesn't handle the case correctly if \$middle < first < last\$. Even though `first` should be assigned as pivot, `last` will be.

The fix is simple: Change `pivot = last;` to `pivot = std::min(first, last);`.

#### Consequences

These two bugs allow for runtime complexity to degrade to \$\mathcal{O}(n^2)\$, because they introduce a huge bias towards `last` as pivot value:

For any call with `p >= 4`, `middle` will have the value of an element to the left of `data[p]`, thus being guaranteed to be smaller than `first` or `last` due to previous runs of `_partition`. So `last will be chosen as pivot, due to bug #2.

For any call with `p == 2` or `p == 3`, `middle` will be assigned the value of `data[1]`, which is equal to `first`. In that case, `pivot` will always be assigned the value of `middle`/`first`.

For any call with `p == 0` or `p == 1`, the median calculation will work with a slight bias towards `last` (due to bug #2).

## Partition - Moving values

There seems to be an assumption that `data[r] == pivot`. This might have been a good assumption before due to bug #2, but that isn't necessarily the case once that bug is fixed. There a multiple ways to fix that.

Also, technically it isn't necessary to move values around that are equal to the pivot value: It doesn't actually matter whether they are left or right of the final pivot position.

## Multithreading

The current multithreading solution isn't actually that efficient at using threads: Nearly half the threads at a time are waiting for the others to finish. (The first thread is waiting on threads #2 and #3 it spawned, they then are waiting on threads #4-7, ...)

As mentioned in the comments, this could be fixed by letting the original thread keep working on one of the subsections before waiting, i.e. changing this:

```
        std::thread lower(&quicksort::_sort<T>, this, data, p, q - 1);
        std::thread upper(&quicksort::_sort<T>, this, data, q + 1, r);
        lower.join();
        upper.join();
```

to:

```
        std::thread lower(&quicksort::_sort<T>, this, data, p, q - 1);
        _sort(data, q + 1, r);
        lower.join();
```

Another point to make is that it rarely benefits performance to have a number of threads much larger than the number of available (logical) cores. The final number is likely between #cores and 2 * #cores, but to find the best amount you'll likely need to measure.

#### Bug #3: No protection for concurrent calls

Since we're already in the multithreaded environment, what happens if a second thread calls `quicksort::sort` after the first thread, but before that call finished?

It resets `thread_count`, thus allowing for the creation of more threads than intended. Once they are finished, `thread_count` will be negative! This might cause problems if that case isn't expected.

Solution: Either don't reset `thread_count`, or wait until it reaches zero before starting to work on the next dataset.

Comment: If you're after the best quicksort performance, you might want to look into sentinel-based partition (e.g. [this talk, around minute 28](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AxnotgLql0k)) and/or parallel partition algorithms.

Comment: Jeez, thanks for the input. And about Bug #3 - I call `sort()` in a loop, yes, but if I join every thread, then I don't think there will be situation, where I call another `sort()` if the previous did not finish

Comment: @Frynio: A loop on the same thread doesn't matter (one call will have finished before the next starts). However, if there ever would be two threads calling `sort` concurrently, then you would get issues.

Comment: Yes, that's true. Fortunately that's not the case

Comment: Why could the overflow only occur if both `p` and `r` are equal to `INT_MAX`?  If they *sum* to more than `INT_MAX`, we have undefined behaviour, and that's perfectly possible if `p == r == INT_MAX - 1`, for example.  The fix is involves use of an unsigned type, and halving the difference between the two (search for "safe median without overflow").

Comment: @TobySpeight uh, yeah. Not sure what I was thinking when I wrote that part.

Answer (score 4):

- Thread creation is an expensive operation, and you do it way more than needed. Even though the number of threads running at any given time is capped, the threads are constantly joined and recreated over and over again (I run your code with cap of 10, over a 1000000-strong array, and counted 50 thread creations). Use a thread pool instead.
- There is no need to start *two* threads. The calling thread may very well continue sorting one of the halves.
- As said in comments, using more threads than hardware supports will cause slowdown. The software threads are beneficial only when they have natural blocking points (due to IO or synchronization). Sorting is not the case here.

Comment: Great points! So after fixing the first two problems you mentioned, should I actually limit the threads only to match my hardware threads?